# Многопоточность в Go

Tags: golang, map

Cколько горутин могут потокобезопасно читать данные из одной map’ы?

Comment: если Ваши горутины только читают,  то нет никаких проблем. Читать может сколько угодно.

Comment: все верно. ограничений на чтение нет.